# Where should Service Providers live?

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

I'm in a dilemma that might look silly. Where should Service Providers live?

On a dedicated `Providers` folder:

```
- Providers
  - CarProvider.foo
  - UserProvider.foo
- Cars
  - Car.foo
- Users
  - User.foo
```

In the same folder for the Service it provides

```
- Cars
  - Car.foo
  - CarProvider.foo
- Users
  - User.foo
  - UserProvider.foo
```

Having them on the same folder makes it easier for the developer to navigate between the Provider and the Service classes in question, so I tend to like it more. But some major projects I've seen use a dedicated folder for the Providers, so it got me thinking if there's a good reason for that...?

Comment: I don't understand the question, as I am lacking the context. Are you talking about the layout of your source code files? What do you mean by service providers? User and UserProvider classes, components, interfaces?

Comment: @Helena OP asks about directory layout in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

The dedicated provider folder encourages separation of concerns, in reminding everybody that there is a boundary between the provider and the underlying object.

In practice, if the implementation of a `Car` is changing, there should be no reason to change `CarProvider`, and if the interface of `Car` is changing, there might be other classes than `CarProvider` that might need to change.

The underlying object may also be reused in other projects in which a different Provider could be needed.

Depending on your design, `Provider` folder  could also facilitate composed services, where the service provided are relying on several objects (e.g. `CarAllocationProvider` may just invoke a `User` and a `Car` operation: you would not start to care about where to put it.

But ultimately, with modern editors and sound design practices, all this doesn’t really matter so much. Typically the distribution of responsibilities between teams or developers could matter much more in such location decision.